# Parsing date in Angular UI datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui

I would like to input an ISO date string as the input to the Angular UI [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="shortDate" ng-model="vm.item.expire"/>
```

The codebase now contains a [dateParser](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/bd2ae0ee02ae384f0ce12f61fadf16f8cb1ea658) service which I assume is there for converting ngModel strings to Date. However it does not work for me. Looking through the code I see that the `parseDate` $parser function is never called. I am not super clear on when this parser should be invoked though.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I create this directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('datepickerPopup', [function() {
  return {
   restrict: 'EA',
   require: 'ngModel',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
     ngModel.$validators = [];
   }
 };
}]);
```

Still validates dates and now accepts string input. I am a litte unclear as to where the validation is now coming from though but it does work.